# CentOS6.0にPython3.7.2の開発環境を構築する（管理者権限なし）

Tags: python, python3, centos

お世話になります。今年エンジニア就職した、駆け出しエンジニアです。

この度CentOS6.0上にPython3.7.2の開発環境を整えることになりましたが、管理者権限がなく、sudo, yum、git cloneコマンドも使えない状況です。
最初はpyenvを入れようとしましたが、`git clone`が使えないので一旦あきらめて、Python3.7.2をインストールしようとしています。

3.7.2に必要な外部ライブラリのインストールを進めており、tarやtgzで提供されているライブラリは`./configure --prefix==/home/username/`と`make`, `make install`でインストールしているのですが、rpmでしか提供されていないライブラリのインストールでは`--prefix`指定してもインストール先を変更できず、止まってしまっています。

大変恐縮なのですが、助言いただけますと大変助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。
本日でスタックして二日目なので、変な汗をかいています。

Comment: 古いですがこの辺が参考になれば。[管理者権限なしでpython3.4をインストールする 改訂2015/05/20](http://matsuhon.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/06/18/171230)、[管理者権限のない環境で Python を構成する](http://koiroha.blogspot.com/2014/07/setup-python-without-admin-permission-using-virtualenv.html)、[root権限がないLinuxでのサバイバル術](https://kivantium.net/linux-without-root)

Comment: `git clone`が使えないのはどんな理由からですか？(サーバから直接外部ネットワークにつなぐのは不可等)。`pyenv`自身を入れるだけであれば、`git clone`の代わりにGitHubからアーカイブを取得して展開するだけで済みそうです。ただしバージョン切り替えを行うタイミングでネットワークに繋ぐでしょうから、ここが理由で`pyenv`を諦めているのかもしれません。

Comment: あと、こんなのが見つかりました。[管理者権限を使わずにサーバに好きなコマンドを簡単にインストールできるようにするLinuxbrew](https://qiita.com/Koutaru/items/7ce631146cc68ccfefc9)

Comment: @kunif 質問文には目を通しましたか？「git cloneが使えない」と書かれているのに、挙げられたリンク先のいくつかはgit clone経由でのインストール手順しか書かれていなくて、そのままだとやや不親切に感じます。

Comment: @kunif @cubick ありがとうございます！`git clone`が使えない理由ですが、gitインストールに必要なライブラリのインストールでMSGFMT po/de.msg make[1]: *** [po/de.msg] Error 127が出てしまい、引っかかっています。

Comment: @cubickさん、使えない理由が不明なのと、git をソースからインストールする記事があったので、組み合わせれば出来るかも？と思いまして。いずれにせよ、詳しい情報は本人しか分からないので、その先の調査と創意工夫は本人に頑張ってもらわないと。

Comment: もしも Githubからgit clone したいのでしたら、代わりにZipでダウンロードして、SCPでCentOS6 に保存する というやり方があります。

Comment: @take88 ありがとうございます！情報が小出しとなってしまい申し訳ございませんが、`wget`は使用できる状態ですので`wget`でファイルを入手しています。

Comment: @Ryoya Ozakiさん、それは先に「Gitがソースからインストール出来ない」で質問した方が良かったのでは？ `gettext` が入っていないという理由が多いようですが。[CentOS 6.3にGit1.8.1をインストール](https://ameblo.jp/rb26/entry-11443985212.html), [gitをコンパイルしたらエラーが出たときの対処法](http://dqn.sakusakutto.jp/2011/08/git-error.html), [gitをソースからインストールする際、makeでtclsh failed; using unoptimized loadingとか出て失敗する場合の対処法](https://qiita.com/yusukaaay/items/6a39cc2f983cb0319bd1), [(CentOS(6.x)向け)root権限がないサーバで必要なパッケージを自分でソースビルドしてporgでパッケージ管理する](https://qiita.com/Tats_U_/items/9247c53db65ba5d55df9)

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りですね。今回はpython3.7.2が動けば良く、gitを入れることが目的ではない為、こういう質問の仕方をしました。python3.7.2を直接入れようとするとmakeで_ctype moduleが見つけられないというメッセージが出てしまいます。

Answer (score 2):

python自体はともかく、本来RPMで提供されているような依存ライブラリまで別にビルドしてインストールする事は勧められません。本当にそれが求められてることなのか確認した方がよいです。

- CentOSのRPMは、古いバージョンをベースにセキュリティ更新をバックポートしているものなので、同じバージョン表記でも開発元が配布しているものとは中身が異なります。
- 自分でビルドしたときとRPMのビルドオプションが異なっていることが大いにありえます。
- 単純にインストールパスが異なる事で起こるトラブルもあります。
- 開発用パッケージ(ヘッダファイルなど)が不足しているだけでもライブラリ全体をインストールすることになります。ダイナミックリンク先がどちらになるか意識する必要があります